# How to check if text overflows a rectangle in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drawing

I drawn a rectangle in Tkinter. Then I wrote text inside the rectangle. But when I unzoom in my canvas, the text is getting bigger and it overflows the rectangle. So I want to check if the text overflows the rectangle in order to resize this text or totally remove it. How can I check this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [bbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) command to get the coordinates of a rectangle that completely encloses the text. Then, you can compare that to the coordinates of the actual rectangle you've drawn around the text.

Comment: Thanks, it functions. I chose to remove the text with `delete(item)` but I don't know how to replace the text when I unzoom. I don't want to manually recreate the text with `create_text()`. Does any function exist to make it run ?

Comment: @Vince: the canvas [itemconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemcget-method) method lets you change the text, if you don't delete the object.

Comment: I used this method `canvas.itemconfigure("text", text="")` in order to hide the text but I don't know what to put to redisplay the text.